# SVN Server source code is not upating?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am new to SVN. I created SVN Server Manager on Windows Server 2012 R2 using this tutorial:

Install VisualSVN: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGIo9_x-YSo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGIo9_x-YSo%5D)

After Import source code in the SVN server manager then I able to check out in to local system.

I modified the file and commited , but I unable to see my latest source code in the server side that where i was imported folder.

ex:  I have 'X' folder in the server , so then i imported in to SVN.
     So then I checkout into local system and I modified some file in the X folder. 
     After I commit those changes should be effect in to 'X' folder in the server side.

Where I will get Latest Source Code in the Sever Side  ?

Comment: You should learn the SVN workflow. The server folder won't automatically update with the code - it only stores the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129933/tutorial-to-get-started-with-learning-subversion for getting started.

Comment: @Narsa how do you see if your server got the last version? Do you use a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it sounds to me like you just need to run an `update` on the folder from the server side to pull in the things that were committed on your local system?